# Align x labels in flipped bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to align all of my x-labels, where they are left justified, and start from the same point. In the code below, when I set `hjust=-.01`, it basically looks correct:

[image]

However, if I try to nudge it a bit further to the right, by setting `hjust=-.05`, everything falls out of alignment:

[image]

```
ggplot(dt.summ, aes(x=reorder(dialogue_act,n), y=n)) +
  geom_col(aes(alpha=.3)) +
  geom_text(aes(y=-.5, x=dialogue_act, label=dialogue_act), hjust=-.01, size=3) +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  coord_flip()
```

How can I correct this?

Data:

```
> print(dt.summ, n=nrow(dt.summ))
# A tibble: 27 × 2
   dialogue_act                     n
   <chr>                        <int>
 1 Statement-non-opinion         2650
 2 Statement-opinion              666
 3 Yes-No-Question                483
 4 Wh-Question                    255
 5 Appreciation                   211
 6 Conventional-closing           107
 7 Conventional-opening            83
 8 Agree/Accept                    77
 9 Declarative Yes-No-Question     71
10 Acknowledge (Backchannel)       60
11 Open-Question                   56
12 Action-directive                27
13 Repeat-phrase                   22
14 Quotation                       18
15 Collaborative Completion        16
16 Signal-non-understanding        13
17 Negative Non-no Answers         11
18 Backchannel in Question Form     8
19 No Answers                       8
20 Apology                          7
21 Hold Before Answer/Agreement     7
22 Or-Clause                        6
23 Rhetorical-Question              6
24 Offers, Options Commits          4
25 Hedge                            3
26 Other                            2
27 Self-talk                        2
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question. Changed `hjust=0` and `aes(y=100)`.

```
ggplot(dt.summ, aes(x=reorder(dialogue_act,n), y=n)) +
  geom_col(aes(alpha=.3)) +
  geom_text(aes(y=100, x=dialogue_act, label=dialogue_act), hjust=0, size=3) +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  coord_flip()
```